# How to arrange a Rectangle inside QML's Pane?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

The following code results in this: Please consider only the pink box with blue border and blue box inside.

[image]

I want to arrange that blue `Rectangle` in the right side of the pink box. What's the way to achieve that? Why are the anchors failing?

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-pane.html

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window
{
    id: window;    visible: true;     width: 1000;     height: 1000

    Pane
    {
       id: pane
       anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
       anchors.bottomMargin: 10
       height: 50; width: 200
       Layout.fillWidth:   true

       background:
          Rectangle
          {
            id: rect
            height: parent.height; width: parent.width
            color: "pink";
            border.color: "blue";
            border.width: 2
          }

       RowLayout
       {
          width: parent.width; height: 50

          Flickable
          {
              id: flickable
              parent: rect
              anchors.fill: parent

              TextArea.flickable:
                  TextArea
                  {
                      id: messageField
                      text: "TextArea"
                      wrapMode: TextArea.Wrap
                  }

              ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
          }

          Rectangle
          {
             id: sendButton

             parent: rect
             anchors.right: rect.right; anchors.rightMargin: 2
             anchors.top: rect.top; anchors.topMargin: 2

             height: 20; width: 20
             color: "blue"
          }
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is because of the rowlayout if you define blue rectangle outside the row layout it will assign to your anchor. rowlayout will override the alignment anchors.